# Declaração DOCTYPE do HTML

Tags: html, html5

Pelas normas da W3C devemos declarar assim: `< ! DOCTYPE html >`, porém vi em um site que eles declararam somente isso: `< ! DOCTYPE >`, o valor semântico é perdido ou o *browser* lê o arquivo normalmente como HTML5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [especificação](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) precisa ser completo.

Os navegadores costumam aceitar sem porque eles tentam dar compatibilidade a código mal escrito, mas está errado. E pode não produzir o resultado esperado, já que ele pode interpretar como quiser quando não há a declaração de acordo com a especificação. Ele tenta te ajudar, mas pode atrapalhar.

O correto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/DocType.html).

Comment: A pergunta é boa e já estava negativada.

Answer (score -5):

Não há obrigatoriedade, a utilização depende do seu propósito, mas sem o "html" o navegador entenderá que é o HTML padrão e não um outro antigo como o "XHTML 1.1 DTD".

Comment: Há obrigatoriedade sim, senão não é HTML5. Em XHTML 5 pode ser omitido, mas correndo o risco de ser interpretado em _quirks mode_. Aqui tem um resumo legal: http://www.doctype.org/